# need help applying loop cuts and making the face round out

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, proportional-editing

I'm new to Blender and I'm in the process of trying to create this screen and I would like for the screen to be rounded with a slight hump rather than just have a drop off on the front like it shows in the picture.

I want the screen to have a smoke arch like the Apple Vision Pro

[image]

Comment: Hello please show some reference images

Comment: MM101 .. Not everyone knows what a Vision Pro is.. please illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe begin by drawing the shape:

[image]

Extrude inwards:

[image]

Fill the center with quads:

[image]

Create edge loops:

[image]

Pull the faces to round the shape:

[image]

Here is what it gives with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Very generous.. considering no ref. supplied... :)